# Putting several textfields into one arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, addition

I´m quite the noob when it comes to coding. I am about to create a programme where you can add the title (String), author (String), release year (int) and genre (String) of a book from writing it in textfields. These things are supposed to be saved in an arraylist. I can not figure out how to add all of these items to the same slot in the arraylist. Please help as fast as possible.

Comment: You could create a class called book, with the fields; title, author, yearPublished, and genre, then pass these objects into an ArrayList

Comment: @MattBrzezinski I agree with you.  This should definitely be put in a class.  This is what classes are made for.

Comment: @Forseth11  How can this class look like? All of my attempts sadly fail

Comment: @Bosse I posted an answer. I will add a class example. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to create a book class with getters/setters.

```
public class Book {
    public String title; 
    public String author; 
    public int year; 
    public String genre; 
}
```

Then you create a Book

```
Book book = new Book();
```

use the setters to set the instance variables (or you can do this when creating book object if you have a constructor with appropriate parameters)

```
book.setAuthor("R.L.Stein");
```

once all the fields are set you add the book to an array list.

```
ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(); 
books.add(book);
```

To print, you should have a toString() method in you book class

```
public String toString(){
   return "Title: "+title+"\nAuthor: "+author+"\nYear: "+year+"\nGenre: "+
        genre; 
}
```

Now when you print a book object it will show all its information. It's best to then use a loop to iterate through the list and print each book in books

```
for(int i=0; i<books.size(); i++){
   System.println(books.get(i)); 
}
```

Comment: How can i after doing these steps display the entire arraylist with the help of a for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

Building off of my comment in the original post, here's what your book class should look like:

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String genre;
    private int releaseYear;

    public Book(String title, String author, String genre, int releaseYear) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    }

    public String getTitle() { return this.title; }
    public String getAuthor() { return this.author; }
    public String getGenre() { return this.genre; }
    public int getReleaseYear() { return this.releaseYear; }
}
```

Now all you need to do is create multiple instances of these classes, and add them into your ArrayList.

Here's a link with some examples of how to use ArrayLists: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-initialize-an-arraylist/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

1. Create a class containing the **title (String), author (String), release year (int) and genre (String)** and create a new instance of that class and add it to the array. Here is a javadoc on [classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html).
2. (Not recommended, but still works) You can create an array list with a size of 4.  The array will be an Object to support the integer. Example: `Object[] obj = new Object[]{"title", "author", 2015, "genre"};`  You can then take the array and add it to the other array you wanted to add this information to.

If you want to go with choice two and create a class here is an example:

```
public class Book {

    private String title, author, genre;
    private int releaseYear;

    public Book(String title, String author, int releaseYear, String genre){
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public int getReleaseYear() {
        return releaseYear;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public void setReleaseYear(int releaseYear) {
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    }

}
```

If you wanted to create a new instance of the Book class you would do:

```
Book book = new Book("title", "author", 2015, "genre");
```